# Spring boot + Mongo + JWT

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, jwt

I'm writing the JWTLoginFilter for check the user and authenticate it, but I can't make the request to DB.

This is the code of my Login filter:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import it.gate42.Model.Credential;
import it.gate42.Model.User;
import it.gate42.repository.User.UserRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;

public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JWTLoginFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public JWTLoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        Credential creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), Credential.class);

        User user = null;
        user = userRepository.login(creds);

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                creds.getUsername(),
                creds.getPassword()
        );

        /*return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        creds.getUsername(),
                        creds.getPassword(),
                        Collections.emptyList()
                )
        );*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        LOGGER.info("a: " + auth.toString());
        TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(res, auth.getName());
    }
}
```

Any function call on userRepository I receive a:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at it.gate42.Config.Security.JWTLoginFilter.attemptAuthentication
```

How I can communicate to my DB for check the user? I'm using Spring boot, Jersey, JWT, Mongo and Spring security for filter the route.

Comment: Looks like JWTLoginFilter is not a spring bean that's why Dependency Injection does not work. You should provide spring configuration.

Comment: this is my Security config: https://gist.github.com/paranoiasystem/3e97a1b8d01003045a4cfbf972b5794b

Comment: Try to inject your userRepository into SecurityConfig class, and pass that instance to your filter in constructor.

Comment: it work thanks @MaximTulupov

Comment: @MarcoFerraioli what you are doing inside login i am stuck at the same situation my mongodb is not getting called.

Answer (score 1):

In this same class JWTLoginFilter, add code below:

```
@Bean
public UserRepository userRepository() {
return new UserRepository();
}
```

In the same class, remove this code:

```
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;
```

In the method attemptAuthentication(), change the repository:

```
user = userRepository().login(creds);
```